# Will Rails 3.2 be still supported after the 4.1 release?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, end-of-life

Are there any policies or official statements, when Rails 3.2 will reach its end of life?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't discuss timelines, but might be of some help.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html

Comment: Ok, the gist is: It'll only receive fixes for severe security bugs after the 4.1 release. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your business depends on ongoing security patches for 3.2, you can [buy a long-term support contract for Ruby on Rails 3.2](https://railslts.com).